Proving the Group of Continuous Functions from $\mathbb{N}_{\{\infty\}}\to \mathbb{Z}$ is a Free Abelian Group.
I am taking a course on Topology and Groups and have a question from an exercise sheet which introduces free Abelian groups. We haven't covered these formally yet in the course, so I think the exercise is supposed to show us where the course is heading. I am quite confused about the definition given in the exercise and how to prove the result.
Define $C=C(\mathbb{N}_{\infty},\mathbb{Z})$ as the group of continuous functions from the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ with the binary relation of pointwise addition. These functions represent convergent sequences (with their limit points) in $\mathbb{Z}$. As such, the functions in $C$ are eventually constant for large indices.
The exercise defines free Abelian groups by their universal property. A group $G$ is called $\textit{free abelian}$ on $S\subseteq G$ if for any Abelian group $H$ and set mapping $g:S\to H$, there exists a $\textit{unique}$ homomorphism $f:G\to H$ such that $f\mathord{\upharpoonright_S}=g$.
Then the exercise asks that I prove $C$ is a free Abelian group.
My confusion is the following. Can $S$ be any subset of $G$? Or does it necessarily need to generate $G$?
My attempt at proving $C$ is free Abelian begins by assuming $S$ generates $G$. For example, we can assume that $S$ is the set of functions $$S=\{e_n\in C:n\in \mathbb{N}_{\infty}\}$$ with $$e_n(x)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{ if } x=n \\ 
0 & \text{ o/w} \end{cases}$$ Then $S$ forms a basis for $C$ in the sense that for any $\phi\in C$, $$\phi=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}_{\infty}} \alpha_n(\phi) e_n$$ for some $\alpha_n(\phi)$'s. This sum is finite, since eventually $\phi$ must be a constant function as it is continuous.
Now, fixing any Abelian group $H$ (with binary relation $+_H$) along with mapping $g:E\to H$, we can define the extension $f:C\to H$ as (with $\phi \in C$ and sum over $+_H$), $$f(\phi)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}_{\infty}}\alpha_n(\phi) g(e_n)$$
Clearly, $f\mathord{\upharpoonright_S}=g$ and as $f(\phi+\phi')=f(\phi)+_Hf(\phi')$ for any $\phi,\phi'\in C$, $f$ is a homomorphism. Further, if $f':G\to H$ is another homomorphism such that it's restriction to $S$ is $g$, then $f(e_n)=g(e_n)=f'(e_n)$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{\infty}$. But then $f=f'$ as they act the same on basis elements and are additive.
However, if $S\subseteq G$ is not such that $S$ generates $G$, I am not sure how we get uniqueness of the extension. In particular, say $S$ only contains $e_1$. Then I feel like we can set $$\begin{align*}f(\phi) &= \alpha_1(\phi) g(e_1) \\
f'(\phi) &= \alpha_1(\phi) g(e_1) +_H \alpha_2(\phi) \tilde{h} \end{align*}$$ where $\tilde{h}$ is some element of $H$, and these will be two distinct homomorphisms from $G$ to $H$ which restrict to $g$ on the set $S$. Does $S$ need to generate $G$? Or am I missing something in the definition/in my working and example?

Yes, $S$ needs to generate the free abelian group on $S$. This is equivalent to the uniqueness part in the universal property.
The group $C$ equals the group of integer sequences which are eventually constant. The constant sequences form a subgroup of $C$, and that has a complement, the subgroup of finite sequences. The latter has a well-known basis, the $e_n$ for $n \geq 0$. It is follows that $C$ is free, the basis is $\{1\} \cup \{e_n : n \geq 0\}$, where $1$ is the constant sequence with value $1$. You can also verify this directly with the element-type definition of a basis.
Notice that your basis is not correct since $e_{\infty}$ is not in $C$.

I see! That is much clearer now, thank you. So, to show $C$ is free, is it sufficient to simply fix $S={1} \cup {e_n \ : \ n\geq 0 }$ and prove that $C$ is free on this particular $S$? I don't need to prove that $C$ is free on every $S\subset C$ such that $S$ generates $C$?

Of course not. Please check out the regular definition of a basis that I linked to. Not every generating set is free. In vector spaces it's linear independence.
